# How come e.target.value not rendering when state is set on submit event?

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

The calendar can be seen here https://vfvyoo.csb.app/ since I am not able to put some of the packages in the code snippet.
For some reason I can't get the price input value to render on the calendar after submitted. The title (price description) state is set and the e.target.value is updated on event but the price won't do the same and render.

Code bin: https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-bessie-vfvyoo?file=/src/App.js

Packages used: react-big-calendar, react-datepicker, date-fns

```
import { Calendar, dateFnsLocalizer } from "react-big-calendar";
import format from "date-fns/format";
import parse from "date-fns/parseISO";
import startOfWeek from "date-fns/parseISO";
import getDay from "date-fns/getDay";
import "./styles.css";
import "react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";

const locales = {
  "en-US": require("date-fns/locale/en-US")
}

const localizer = dateFnsLocalizer({
  format,
  parse,
  startOfWeek,
  getDay,
  locales
})

const data = [
  {
    title: "Normal Pricing",
    price: "45",
    start: new Date(2023, 3, 1),
    end: new Date(2023, 3, 4)
  },
  {
    title: "Summer Pricing",
    price: "85",
    start: new Date(2023, 3, 3),
    end: new Date(2023, 3, 10)
  },
  {
    title: "Winter Pricing",
    price: "25",
    start: new Date(2023, 3, 4),
    end: new Date(2023, 3, 4)
  }
];

function App() {
  const [newPriceBlock, setNewPriceBlock] = useState({
    title: "",
    price: "",
    start: "",
    end: ""
  });
  const [allPriceBlocks, setAllPriceBlocks] = useState(data);
  console.log(allPriceBlocks);

  function handleAddPriceBlock() {
    for (let i = 0; i < allPriceBlocks.length; i++) {
      const d1 = new Date(allPriceBlocks[i].start);
      const d2 = new Date(newPriceBlock.start);
      const d3 = new Date(allPriceBlocks[i].end);
      const d4 = new Date(newPriceBlock.end);

      if ((d1 <= d2 && d2 <= d3) || (d1 <= d4 && d4 <= d3)) {
        alert("CLASH");
        break;
      }
    }

    setAllPriceBlocks([...allPriceBlocks, newPriceBlock]);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Seasonal Pricing</h2>
      <div className="price-block-entry">
        <input
          className="description-input"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Price Description"
          value={newPriceBlock.title}
          onChange={(e) =>
            setNewPriceBlock({ ...newPriceBlock, title: e.target.value })
          }
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="50.00"
          value={newPriceBlock.price}
          onChange={(e) =>
            setNewPriceBlock({ ...newPriceBlock, price: e.target.value })
          }
        />
        <DatePicker
          placeholderText="Start Date"
          style={{ height: 500, margin: "50px" }}
          selected={newPriceBlock.start}
          onChange={(start) =>
            setNewPriceBlock({ ...newPriceBlock, start: start })
          }
        />
        <DatePicker
          placeholderText="End Date"
          selected={newPriceBlock.end}
          onChange={(end) => setNewPriceBlock({ ...newPriceBlock, end: end })}
        />
        <button onClick={handleAddPriceBlock}>submit</button>
      </div>
      <Calendar
        localizer={localizer}
        events={allPriceBlocks}
        startAccessor="start"
        endAccessor="end"
        style={{ height: 500, margin: "2%" }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: here the problem is with the props of react-big-calendar. The events prop does not accept the array of object in which object has price as property as it does not have any usage of that and that's why its not working.

Comment: @MilanPatel I had a feeling it was with the calendar props but how do I fix it. Is there a way to get around that?

Comment: There are ways, but it all depends on how you want the price to be displayed.

Comment: I figured it out. There is a components prop where I can pass an event property. That event property is a function. Will post an answer when I can if someone does not. thanks